# AWSCLI s3 sync doesn't create directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Hi try to sync a local directory to a S3 bucket. The files in the directory get synced perfectly, just the directory isn't created at all. Can you guys give me a hint how to do it?

"newdir" contains two textfiles. These are copied to the bucket just fine.

```
 upload: newdir/test.txt to s3://aaa-stuff/test.txt
 upload: newdir/test1.txt to s3://aaa-stuff/test1.txt
```

I used the following command:

```
aws s3 sync newdir/ s3://aaa-stuff --sse --storage-class "REDUCED_REDUNDANCY" --acl "private"
```

I want that the files get copied to the directory `s3://aaa-stuff/newdir`.

Comment: Try with `--recursive` option.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ aws s3 sync newdir/ s3://aaa-stuff/newdir

upload: newdir/file1 to s3://aaa-stuff/newdir/file1
upload: newdir/file2 to s3://aaa-stuff/newdir/file2
```